# Ajax request in Symfony 3.4

Tags: json, ajax, symfony, request

i am using symfony 3.4 , i want to execute a controller action on a button click in my twig template , that's why i used ajax for that : 
first i added the ajax route :

```
ajax_route:
    path:     /ajax_request
    defaults: { _controller: offerBundle:Default:ajax }
    methods: [post]
```

then the controller action :

```
    public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
    {
        $personnage = $request->request->get('personnage');
        dump($request->request);
        $wishlist = new wishlist();
        $wishlist->setUserid($personnage);
        $wishlist->setOfferid(1);
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($wishlist);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

the ajax part :

```
    <script>
        $('.btn').click( function(){
            var personnage = 3;
            $.ajax({
         url: "{{ path('ajax_route') }}",
         type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "personnage": personnage
                },
                async: true,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data)
                }
            })
        });

    </script>
```

this is my html button :

```
<button id="wishlist" class="btn">add to wishlist</button>
```

what happens when i click on the button is i do get this error log :

1 AJAX request
Method :POST    Type:xhr    Status:500  URL:/ajax_request

and the 'var_dump' in the controller dosen't display anything

Comment: Have you checked the log files?

Comment: add `die();` after the dump, and remove `datatype: json,` from your ajax call, you should see the dump in your console, otherwise it may be a routing issue.

Comment: @ArleighHix nothing is executed from the controller i think it's a routing issue because it's not getting the right controller action

Comment: @ehymel my log file :

INFO
21:59:55
request Matched route "afficher_offre".
Show context
INFO
21:59:55
security Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.

Comment: Can you confirm when looking at the site in the browser that `url: "{{ path('ajax_route') }}"` is resolved correctly, i.e. if it shows `url: /ajax_request` in your browser?

Comment: Also your ajaxAction does not return any Response, which it must for the action to work. This could be the cause of the 500 error. Try something like `return new JsonResponse()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is on the route.

**path()**: Generates a relative URL path given a route name and parameters.

**url()** : Generates an absolute URL given a route name and parameters.

in this line use

```
url: "{{ url('ajax_route') }}",
```

Instead

```
url: "{{ path('ajax_route') }}",
```

and your controller

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
*
*

      public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
         $arrayAjax = array("position" => "fasle");
        {
      if (($request->getMethod() == Request::METHOD_POST) && ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())) {

            $personnage = $request->request->get('personnage');
            dump($request->request);
            $wishlist = new wishlist();
            $wishlist->setUserid($personnage);
            $wishlist->setOfferid(1);
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($wishlist);
            $em->flush();
            $arrayAjax = array("position" => "true");
         }
    return new JsonResponse($arrayAjax2);
       }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , i have replaced my code by the one you wrote but i still have the ajax request status 500 , i think it's routing issue because it's not getting to the controller action  the dump is not displayed

Comment: Javascript code is internal or imports the external Javascript file on the page. if codes ajax in external file your URL variable must be something like this-->    url :  window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname+'/ajax_request';  if you are in develope mode you must use it -> url :  window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname+'YourPatch/web/app_dev.php/ajax_request'